# Referencing a renamed column in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make queries and referencing renamed columns but it doesn't seem to work.
I have tried the following:

```
SELECT (Company.email) AS EmailName
FROM   Company
WHERE  EmailName  LIKE '%g%'


SELECT Company.email AS EmailName
FROM   Company
WHERE  EmailName  LIKE '%g%'


SELECT Company.email AS 'EmailName'
FROM   Company
WHERE  EmailName  LIKE '%g%'


SELECT Company.email AS 'EmailName'
FROM   Company
WHERE  'EmailName'  LIKE '%g%'
```

The following error keeps coming up:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'EmailName'.
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot reference a column alias in the same `SELECT` or `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` where it is defined.  A simple way to remember this:  The `FROM` clause defines the columns that are known in the `SELECT`.

Two common methods to handle this are CTEs and subqueries.  But you can also use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT v.EmailName
FROM Company C CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (c.email)
     ) v(EmailName)
WHERE v.EmailName LIKE '%g%';
```

This method is particularly handy if you have chains of expressions that refer to each other, because you can just keep adding more lateral joins (the technical term for what `APPLY` implements).

Comment: Would this method be efficient when used in conjunction with inner joins?

Comment: @Burdy In that particular case, yes. But if you do calculations on the column, then it probably won't use indexes

Comment: @Burdy . . . It should be fine.  The SQL Server optimizer is pretty smart.  However, you might want to test on your data.

Comment: @Burdy You don't need to change a "name" in order to use it for joining.

Answer (score 1):

Even though, the query is written with SELECT... FROM... WHERE, SQL Server processes them in different order.

The below is the order of processing. [Official MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> 1.FROM
> 2.ON
> 3.JOIN
> 4.WHERE
> 5.GROUP BY
> 6.WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7.HAVING
> 8.SELECT
> 9.DISTINCT
> 10.ORDER BY
> 11.TOP

So, as the WHERE clause comes before SELECT clause. So, WHERE clause does not have context of the aliases defined in the SELECT clause. So, you are getting error.

What you can do instead is:

- Go for derived table

```sql
SELECT EmailName 
FROM
(
SELECT (Company.email) AS EmailName
FROM   Company ) AS t
WHERE  t.EmailName  LIKE '%g%'
```

- Go for common table expression (CTE)

```sql
;WITH CTE_Email AS
(
SELECT (Company.email) AS EmailName
FROM   Company
)
SELECT EmailName FROM CTE_Email 
WHERE EmailName  LIKE '%g%'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use a derived table

```
select t.EmailName 
from   ( select (Company.email) as EmailName
         from   Company 
       ) t
WHERE  t.EmailName  LIKE '%g%'
```

but why do you need it ?
what is wrong with

```
select (Company.email) as EmailName
from   Company 
where  (Company.email) like '%g%'
```